# Publish package into local Verdaccio registry overriding .npmrc

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface, verdaccio

Trying to publish package into local [Verdaccio](https://verdaccio.org/docs/setup-npm) registry.

Tried to run `npm publish --registry http://localhost:4873` but it is trying to publish package into production **Nexus** which is specified in `.npmrc` file. When manually changing `.npmrc` with local registry URL it works fine, as expected, but I don't want to do it like this as I need [Verdaccio](https://verdaccio.org/docs/setup-npm) only for testing locally.

Is there a way to override `.npmrc` and specify registry from command line?